# Calculating probabilities using multi-dimensional statistical distributions

Tags: core-language

```
Probability[Max[x,y]-Min[x,y]<1/3,{x,y}\[Distributed]UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]
```

Why doesn't *Mathematica* calculate this query?

```
Probability[
 Max[x, y] - Min[x, y] < 1/3, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]
```

Comment: Oy, I made a bad edit to the question. If anybody has the power to undo it, please do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either specify a distribution for each variable:

```
 {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
  y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}
```

Or use a multivariate one:

```
 {x, y} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
```

In this case it also equivalent to:

```
 {x, y} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

Using [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html):

```
td = TransformedDistribution[
   Max[x, y] - Min[x, y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[2]];
CDF[td, 1/3]
```

Visualizing function:

```
ContourPlot[Max[x, y] - Min[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Contours -> {{1/3}}]
area = 1 - (2/3)^2
```

Using [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   Max[x, y] - Min[x, y] < 1/3, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
RegionPlot[reg]
Area[reg]
```

[image]